# How can I get assembly.dll.config file?

Tags: .net, dll, configuration

How can I get ahold of assembly.dll.config in the bin of an executing application in .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code in the past to get the config file as an XmlDocument (Please note that this assumes the '.config' extension on the config file):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
string cfgFile = asm.CodeBase + ".config";
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(new XmlTextReader(cfgFile));
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach a config file for a .NET library (dll) is not a good approach. What if this dll is installed into GAC? Where is the config file supposed to be loaded? All settings are recommended to be stored in app.config for the executable.

Comment: What about scenarios where we have to develop DLL plugins to existing applications that lets you for example extend the existing application via toolbars.  Our Toolbars are almost standalone applications inside the main application and do need separate database etc.  So in this case where so you store the config information ?

Comment: You don't need to modify the existing application's binaries then. Simply hook your DLL settings into that application's config file (yes, you must create a app.config for that exe, or modify the existing one). The impact is still minimal, and no need to create a separate config file for your dll.

Answer (score 1):

[ConfigurationManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) ???

String strPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);